# What is the de facto standard for Action/Func classes?

Tags: java

Because the JDK doesn't contain them, a zillion of 3rd party libraries contain Action or Func interfaces, that look something like:

```
public interface Action<T> {
  void doSomething(T item);
}

public interface Func<TResult, TInput> {
  TResult doSomething(TInput input);
}
```

What is the de-facto, or most commonly used standard for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) (void) or [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (returning a value).  But as you note, packages often create their own.  Part of the reason is to have a more meaningful name than `run` or `call`.  You should note that Java does not have C#-style delegates, nor does it currently have a way to implicitly convert between a method and an instance of an interface.

Note that neither of the above interfaces allows parameters.  If you need to, you will need a different solution.

EDIT: I have used Apache Functor in the past, and it has some of these interfaces (e.g. [`UnaryProcedure`](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/UnaryProcedure.html) and [`UnaryFunction`](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/UnaryFunction.html) for the ones in the question).  However, I would still consider creating your own, especially if you don't need anything else from Functor (e.g. an [algorithm](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/core/algorithm/package-summary.html) or [adapter](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/adapter/package-summary.html))

Comment: JDK7 (or 8?) is supposed to remove the need for these one-method interfaces (and a name for the method). They can then be replaced by closures (which will also be able to accept parameters).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough - I also need to pass in generic arguments. See edited question.

Comment: @ripper, I don't know an equivalent for that signature.

Comment: I can't believe you've never needed something like this yourself. It's awfully useful (working around Java's lack of closures/delegates)

Comment: @Thilo: You've got it wrong. Java's lambdas aren't going to eliminate the need for single abstract method (SAM) interfaces, they're going to make it easy to create instances of those interfaces as lambdas and use method references for them, etc.

Comment: @ripper, actually, there is [Apache Functor](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/).

Comment: @ColinD: That (being able to get an SAM from a lambda in order to call a method that needs one) is a nice compatibility feature, but new API will probably not create extra SAM (like Runnable, Callable, EventHandler) anymore and just accept these lambdas directly.

Comment: @Thilo: What I'm saying is that (unless the people working on the feature change their minds about this, which I think is unlikely), _there will be no function types_ and all APIs that want to take advantage of lambdas will have to accept SAM interfaces/abstract classes just like they do now. I'm not speculating here; I follow the lambda-dev mailing list and function types were removed months ago.

Comment: @Thilo: A lot of people consider the approach they're taking to be better, since interfaces can have useful names and document what they're intended to do (and the behavioral contract they require all implementations to follow), while a function type such as "a function that takes a `String` and an `int` and returns a `boolean`" cannot. And while it may be a little more work on the part of API designers to create an interface for each type of function their API needs to take (if one doesn't already exist), there really isn't any additional burden on API _users_.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know of any interface that matches your `Action<T>` signature (possibly partly because such a signature mandates that instances of `Action` produce side effects), [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) interface that matches the second signature, plus lots of `Collection` and `Iterable` related utilities that make use of `Function`s to do lazy mapping (called `transform` in Guava). It's also just a really great general-purpose Java library.

Comment: Action is useful because sometimes, you just need a side effect, and you don't want to enforce your client code to return anything.