# LINQ's Single in java?

Tags: java, linq, lambdaj

Is there an equivalent to LINQ's [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) in java? Perhaps in [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)?

Comment: Check this one: github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light, example:new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).toList().distinct();

Comment: jpropel seems nice, but I can't find it in maven repo. too bad ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):**

[Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterable< T > iterable)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

Comment: I was going to look for an example in Guava, but my network connection died :)

Answer (score 8):

It's a pretty easy one to implement yourself, to be honest:

```
public static <T> T single(Iterable<T> source) {
  Iterator<T> iterator = source.iterator();
  if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No elements");
  }
  T first = iterator.next();
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("More than one element");
  }
  return first;
}
```

(Or put it in a generic class instead of making the method generic. You may decide to use a different exception type, too.)

Comment: Still, I prefer @Emil's answer, assuming guava is lightweight enough. With Maven, importing 3rd party libraries is so easy that "integrate a new library" barrier is lowered. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263607/what-is-the-de-facto-standard-for-action-func-classes

Comment: BTW, where were you in the last few days??? I asked about 25 questions in the last few days, some of them are still unanswered, and I'm sure you know the answers to 90% of them :) Almost all of them more important than this question... http://stackoverflow.com/users/11236/ripper234

Comment: @ripper234: Oh Guava is a wonderful library, and if you're happy to use an extra library, it's *absolutely* worth having. And looking at the first couple of pages of your questions, they're database-related ones which I wouldn't know :(

Answer (score 0):

A less defensive version of @Jon's solution.

```
Collection<T> coll;
T first = col.iterator().next();
```

Add checks to taste.

Comment: That would be closer to LINQ's `First` method.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use my [xpresso](https://github.com/WantedTechnologies/xpresso) library you can write: `x.list(iterable).toScalar();`